# FMEDA failure mode distribution data

Tags: automotive, component-failure

We are developing an automotive product according to ISO 26262 standard. For FMEDA calculations failure mode and failure mode distribution is required.
Some sources to find these are IEC 61709 standard and the book from Birolini.
However not all failure modes and distributions are listed in there.
I'm still looking for failure mode and distribution of the following components:
- High-side unipolar current sense monitor
- Rail to rail opamp
- Differential Comparator
- Constant Current Regulator
- Voltage regulator
- Real time clock
- Some 74xx logic
I contacted the manufacturers, but I did not receive a satisfying response.
Does anybody know where to find these failure modes and distributions?

Thanks in advance,

Marcel

Comment: Have you tried looking up the RIAC's FMD 97 handbook? I think most of the components you are looking for are listed there. I remember seeing Op-amp, comparator, voltage regulator, RTC.

Comment: Thanks user225296, I found an old copy of FMD-91, but did not know if that data could be used. I finished the FMEDA a while ago, but for new projects I will consider FMD-97.